# Configure Apache 503 sensitivity

Tags: linux, nginx, mysql, apache2

I Currently have a service with a very high traffic (about 1000 connections/second, and this is not reducable with optimization anymore). Until 1 week ago, I was at AWS and had twiched some of my apache/NGNIX configurations to handle that load. There was no issue at all.

I now want to change host and I went with OVH ; the new server config is 4x better than the latter (128GO RAM, 24 Core last gen processor with 30mb cache...)

Now comes the issue ; on the new server I somehow get 503 errors (by apache) as soon as I pass the 600 connections per second. - First of all : Of course I know I must loadbalance the connections and I intend too ; but I want a clean config before i replicate it. - Apache is configured to handle 4000 concurrent connections and it does when I stress test simple

So my Hypothesis : - Either OVH (new host) blocks my internal connections when too often. But they tell me they only block if I go over the 1GB/S bandwith (I don't - far from it) - Either Apache configuration is a bit different and makes server go into 503 faster than before (maby it doesnt like the 0,5 second between connecting to mysql and getting an result). Indeed there is a major difference ; on the new server (Ubuntu) my apache is behind an NGNIX reverse proxy and is in a docker-container whereas before it was a simple LAMP

Does someone have an explanation of what is happening? I am totally lost & depressed.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Do you run Docker with Swarm? What network configuration do you use for the Docker container? Maybe it has to do with TCP backlog. http://www.ryanfrantz.com/posts/apache-tcp-backlog/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No I am not using SWARM. The network configurations are the default NGNIX ones (i am always using NGNIX as reverse-proxies). I looked at the TCP backlogs and I clearly had issues there. There where warnings on my somaxconn. However fixing these issues did not actually fix the issue I am currently confronted to. :(

I have the feeling that apache goes into 503 mode as soon as I call external services (other services) although the pings and response times seem fine.

Comment: Additional info : I stresstested my redis directly at the same time as i stress tested the apache. Apache downed at 150 connections/s whilst redis was fine at 15k connections/s

Comment: If you call a apache page that just returns a static html file, a 404, or the server-status handler, the 503's go away?

Comment: Yes on simple apache calls (either static files or even simple echos in php) I can go up to 3000 connections/s without getting any 503s.

Comment: And the normal backend that involves PHP calling mysql and other services over sockets or TCP with internal/external addresses?

Comment: As soon as there is mysql connections or TCP (only external in my case) the amount of connections/s drop drastically.
When stress testing apache; I can go up to 150 c/s for a simple MYSQL query (the query takes 0,011s MAX) and 110 c/s for a redis query.
I stress tested directly both mysql and redis (thinking they had config issues) without passing though Apache but i have no problems. Redis can go up to 15 c/s and MYSQL can go to 2700 c/s. It only is an issue when i run a service through apache.

Comment: PHP is Apache module? Do you use sockets or TCP for mysql and redis from PHP?

Comment: PHP is used with the Apache module, Yes. And for the PHP connections we use TCP only.

Comment: Socket connections would have less overhead. Also mysql has backlog settings itself. https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/01/06/mysql-high-number-connections-per-secon/

Comment: It seems to me that if you get a 503 then this must mean the number of Apache workers has maxed out. If you look at the scoreboard in /server-status, do you have the expected number of slots?

Answer (score 0):

The answer were the backlog configurations. You can find some on your linux system (on your docker) but also on mysql, on mongodb ect...
When you have high traffic, you need to twitch those settings as well.

I also changed the limit of TCP connections ; by default these are limited by Linux.